# String Comparision in If condition in PL/SQL

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, plsql, oracle12c

I have the following code

```
create or replace procedure deact_user (i_email in varchar2)
as
  var1 varchar2(200);

begin
  for em_id in (select abc.emai_id from abc)
  loop
    if (i_email <> em_id) then
      dbms_output.put_line('Not working');
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('Working');
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

I need to compare the i_email which is a input parameter with em_id which is a for loop which loops the table abc having field as emai_id. 
Iam facing error PLS=00306 wrong type of arguments in call to '!='
Please help

Comment: btw there is no need for brackets around `if` conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a for loop with select, its creates a record type. To access the value, you have to change your if to this:

```
if (I_email <> em_id.emai_id) 
.....
```

That should solve your problem. Now, on the other hand, it would be quicker  (and easier) to just query with a where clause using your variable. (that way, you wouldn't need a for loop).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Cursors for read content and compare values like this:

```
    create or replace procedure deact_user (i_email in varchar2)
as
  var_id varchar2(200);

 cursor cur_em_id is select abc.emai_id from abc;

    begin
      open cur_em_id;
      loop
       fetch cur_em_id into var_id;
       exit when cur_em_id%NOTFOUND;
        if (i_email <> var_id) then
          dbms_output.put_line('Not working');
        else
          dbms_output.put_line('Working');
        end if;
      end loop;
    close cur_em_id;
    end;
```